# Using a Java library to grab an IRC user's IP address

Tags: java, ip-address, irc

Are there any IRC libraries available for Java that would allow me to grab a user's IP address?

Answer (score 2):

More importantly, the IRC protocol doesn't let you see other users' IP addresses, so, no, there isn't. :)

Comment: That's more a network specific setting than anything. A simple WHOIS on a user returns their IP on a lot of major networks (Freenode, QuakeNet, etc.)